# How to get the instance ID of the specific ibm cloud app instance?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, multiple-instances

We started 2 instances of our IBM cloud app. Now, we want to trace which user belongs to which instance. 
Cf Command or Javascript code needed

Answer (score 1):

You can access various [environment variables](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html) running in the cloud. For example using Node.js `process.env.VCAP_APPLICATION` displays (among other things) the unique application id and `process.env.CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` the index of the specific instance (0,1, etc.).

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-develop-scalable-bluemix-app/cl-develop-scalable-bluemix-app-pdf.pdf) is a nice example from **developerworks** using an older API, but the generall approach is the same.